# logback per-logger configuration is not working

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to disable log output from all external libraries in logback-test.xml. Somehow it does not work as advertised, and I don't understand why.

This is the contents of my logback-test.xml:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Turn off third party chatter -->
    <logger name="httpclient.wire" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="o.s" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.spring" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="OFF"/>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I explicitly turned off org.spring logger, yet I still see all debug output from Spring. However, if I specify different level in  element, it works. Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: Not meaning to ask a stupid question, but are you sure Spring is logging over logback? By default Spring uses JCL, so it would be necessary to add the jcl-over-sl4j jars into your classpath and remove the commons-logging.

Comment: No way stupid, you're right. I added jcl-over-sl4j as project dependency, but commons-logging is also on the classpath. Trying to figure out who pulls it in.

Comment: What are you using for dependency management? Both Maven and Ivy have pre-built reports that can help, i.e., http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/report.html and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And the answer is: know your logger name! All Spring loggers start with org.springframework, not org.spring. After I fixed the name, everything works, even with commons-logging present in the classpath.